# Custom aggregation in Tableau when joining two different types of tables

Tags: tableau-api

I'm fairly new to Tableau, but otherwise pretty well versed in data and SQL, etc.

I'm working on a dashboard that will display some financial data.  The two main categories are "Actual" results and "Plan" (or budget).

The Actual results are at the individual transaction level by cost center and by account.  The Plan is at the cost center and account level.  For example:

Actual table:

```
Cost Center | Account | Amount
______________________________
ABC           10023     500
ABC           10023     600
BAC           10023     250
BAC           10023     300
```

Plan table:

```
Cost Center | Account | Plan Amount
___________________________________
ABC           10023     2000
BAC           10023     2300
```

When joining these two tables together in Tableau, the Plan Amount gets repeated at the transaction level (obviously, as it's a straightforward LEFT JOIN), which in this example for Cost Center ABC would aggregate to a total of 4000, and for BAC it would aggregate to a total of 4600.

What I'm hoping to somehow accomplish is for the Plan Amount to only be aggregated at the cost center level, not at the transaction level.  In the actual tables I'm using, the Cost Center rolls up through a department hierarchy, i.e. a department can have multiple cost centers, etc, and when I show results at a department or division level it really blows up the Plan Amount numbers, they're vastly overstated.

Is there some way to accomplish this in Tableau?  In SQL I'd probably use a window function of some sort to divide the Plan Amount by # of transactions per Cost Center so that it would aggregate correctly (though this would lead to some rounding errors, but not that material).  But don't know how to do this in Tableau.

Comment: This is possibly a better use case for data blending instead of a join. Separate queries combined at the aggregate level. See the help and training materials on blending. Blending has a few tricky edge cases to be careful of but can be a good fit for problems like this.

Comment: Yes, blending did the trick.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When joining it will be put against the transaction level, as with any normal inner join. Therefore you have options on how to handle this.

You could do it using an aggregation - i.e. instead of SUM you could MIN / MAX / AVG the field, which would always return the same value.

Alternatively you could blend this data, rather than join. If you blend in the visualisation layer and only blend it when showing the Cost Centre level, this will prevent aggregating against all transactions. To blend this would be a completely separate data source. It would "blend join" in Tableau - see Data - Edit Blend Relationships in Tableau.